# initializing values of integer variable in round braces in C language

Tags: c

code snippet:

```
void main()  
{  
    int a=1,3,15;//why it is allowed, generating warning no error  
    int b=(1,2,4);//what it signifies writing value in ()  
printf("%d",a+b);  
}
```

I want to know what is use specifying values in round braces???

Comment: Look in your C book about the comma operator.  It allows to write several expressions in sequence giving as result the value of the last one.  It's perfectly legal.  In a variable declaration, it's used by the syntax to separate several variable declarations, so the first one will give an error, as pointed in one of the answers.

Comment: first line gives warning as 'code has no effect' but not error

Comment: sorry, but the declaration `int a=1, 3, 15;` generates an error, just before reading the `3`.  `pru.c:14:15: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant` (gcc (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1) 4.6.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a=1,3,15;
```

is not allowed:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:2:13: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
     int a=1,3,15;
```

This is because it is parsed as a list of declarations, the items being `a=1`, `3`, and `15` (and `3` is not a valid variable name).

If you write

```
int a;
a = 1,3,15;
```

that is parsed as `(a = 1), 3, 15;` because `=` binds tighter than `,`.

On the other hand,

```
int b=(1,2,4);
```

declares a single variable `b` initialized from the expression `(1,2,4)`. The parens are simply for grouping.

`,` (comma) is an operator that evaluates (and throws away the result of) its left operand, then evaluates and returns its right operand. So `b` ends up being `4` (and some compilers will warn about ignoring the values of `1` and `2`).

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis evaluate the expression. Consider:

```
int a = (2, 4);
```

This sets `a` equal to the result of the evaluating the expression `2, 4`.

Your next question is probably what the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) does. It evaluates the first expression, throws the result away, evaluates the second expression, and then the expression evaluates to the type and value of that second expression. So the expression `2, 3`evaluates to 3.

Comment: See also (for an explanation as to why it might be useful): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c

Answer (score 0):

```
int a=1,3,15;
```

is not valid, at least a diagnostic has to generated and the compiler to refuse to translate the code.

```
int b=(1,2,4);
```

is valid and equivalent to:

```
int b=4;
```

The comma expression `(1, 2, 4)` is equivalent to `((1, 2), 4)` and evaluates to `4`.